# Javascript Regex Input Validation to Prevent Duplicate Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to validate text input with the following requirements:

1. allowed characters & length `/^\w{8,15}$/`
2. must contain `/[a-z]+/`
3. must contain `/[A-Z]+/`
4. must contain `/[0-9]+/`
5. must not contain repeated characters (ie. `aba=pass` and `aab=fail`)
6. Each test would return true when used with `.test()`.

With modest familiarity, I am able to write the first 4 tests, albeit individually.  The 5th test is not working out, negated lookahead (which is what i believe i need to be using) is challenging.

Here are a few value/result examples:

```
re.test("Fail1");//returns false, too short

re.test("StringFailsRule1");//returns false, too long

re.test("Fail!");//returns false, invalid !

re.test("FAILRULE2");//returns false, missing [a-z]+

re.test("failrule3");//returns false, missing [A-Z]+

re.test("failRuleFour");//returns false, missing [0-9]+

re.test("failRule55");//returns false, repeat of "5"

re.test("TestValue1");//returns true
```

Finally, the ideal would be a single combined test used to enforce all requirements.

Comment: Do you need to use a regex? It would probably be easier just to loop through the characters in the input string

Comment: It has been my experience that complex string testing is usually best accomplished with RegEx.  Here, setting flags for 2-4 and remembering a prior character for 5 are what pushed me away from individual character comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses negative and positive lookaheads zero-length assertions for your tests and the `.{8,15}` bit validates length.

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])\w{8,15}$
```

For your fifth rule I used a negative lookahead to make sure that a capture group of any character is never followed by itself.

[Regexpal demo](http://www.regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28?!.%2a%28.%29%5C1%29%28?=.%2a%5Ba-z%5D%29%28?=.%2a%5BA-Z%5D%29%28?=.%2a%5B0-9%5D%29%5Cw%7B8,15%7D%24&input=Fail1%0AStringFailsRule1%0AFail!%0AFAILRULE2%0Afailrule3%0AfailRuleFour%0AfailRule55%0ATestValue1)

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w{8,15}                 word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
                           (between 8 and 15 times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```